# Why did getSite() return a FormlibValidation object

Tags: plone, kss

I've installed collective.quickupload on a blank Plone 4.1 site, 
and noticed that when you add a quickupload portlet, kss calls for field validation (plone.app.form.kss), getSite function will return a FormlibValidation object, which cause the quickupload vocabularies crash.

The traceback is here: http://pastebin.com/nvwChpZd

My question is:

- Is that (getSite function returns a FormlibValidation object) a bug or intended behaviour ?
- Solution to fix/work around/make collective.quickupload work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getSite() returns the nearest component site (where local utilities can be stored), which really just means whatever was last set with setSite(), which usually happens on traversal.

Most of the time, the only traversal hook that calls setSite() is the one that's triggered when you traverse over the Plone site. But I think the old KSS inline form validation machinery used (uses?) a hack that creates a local component site on the fly (in a view) and sets that as the local site during the remainder of the request so that it can override certain things.

You can disable validation (e.g. disable the relevant KSS file in portal_kss) or fix c.quickupload to check whether the result of getSite() is an ISiteRoot. If it isn't, it should be acquisition-wrapped, so you can do aq_parent(site) (or maybe site.**parent**) to get the parent in a loop until you find an ISiteRoot.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I ended up disabling KSS validation. The error affected diazo theming, too.